# Possible NVME M.2 and GPU communication channel issue

Tags: linux, graphics-card, motherboard

I just finished building a new PC. After some initial issues solved by changing the RAM slot from A1 to B1, I am having more issues.

First of all, I have finally managed to install Windows 10 and everything is working well. But I am concerned about a possible underlying issue. After some issues installing Windows that were not the fault of the PC but with old inaccurate/imprecise guides, I tried to install Ubuntu off the USB instead (as already mentioned, Windows is now successfully installed). This got me to the install screen for Ubuntu, but everything was extremely slow to progress, and would eventually freeze up and be unable to interact with. These were the errors appearing in the installer's stdout:

[image]

That led me here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327730/what-causes-this-pcieport-00000003-0-pcie-bus-error-aer-bad-tlp#369090

Adding the kernel option `pci=nommconf` for the boot from USB actually fixed this sluggishness-then-freeze and I was able to install Ubuntu from the USB. I also had to add `pci=nommconf` in `/etc/default/grub` after install as otherwise *eventually* Ubuntu would completely freeze up and require a hard shutdown by the case button. Even with this option I've had a couple of crashes, though it managed to run fine, including running Civilisation V and a few other things, for around 30 minutes. I stress *fine*: it was really terrible compared to what was eventually possible once Windows was installed.

What is said in the UNIX Stack Exchange answer may point to my issue:

> It may be a hardware bug in the device, in the PCIe root controller on the motherboard, in the specific interaction of those two, or something else.

None of the three suggested potential solutions in the answers to that question work for me. First:

> The X99 Deluxe II motherboard shares bandwidth between PCIE16_3 slot and M.2/U.2. Following comment from @Nic, in the BIOS I changed Onboard Devices Configuration | U.2_2 Bandwidth from Auto to U.2_2. This fixed the problem for me.

There is no such "U.2_2 Bandwidth" option in my BIOS as far as I can see, so this doesn't help. There is a mode option for the M.2, which I changed from "Auto" to "PCI" (other alternative being SATA), though this didn't fix anything.

> I changed the PCIE16_3 slot Config in Bios on my x99-E to be static set to x8 mode instead of auto that is default for M.2 device support. Works fine now without TLP errors on both of my 1070GTX cards connected via PCIe 1x to 16x extension boards.

I can't find that setting in my BIOS. I cannot physically move the GPU to the other slot because I have a WiFi card installed that is in the way, and which I need.

PCI generation for the video card is mentioned somewhere but I don't want to trial and error all the possible related BIOS settings on the off-chance it helps; would like to have good reason to try, especially now things are just working on Windows.

> Search your motherboard manual for "AER". You can kill the source of the problem by either correcting the specific incompatibility or disabling AER altogether. Only use this if all the error spam concerns corrected errors, otherwise you could be covering up an actual issue.

I can't find "AER" mentioned anywhere in my manual. You can find the motherboard manual here:

https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1200/PRIME_B560M-A/E18905_PRIME_B560M-A_v2_UM_WEB.pdf?model=PRIME%20B560M-A

Outut of `inxi -F`:

```
System:
  Host: <deleted for privacy> Kernel: 5.15.0-58-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.5 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: ASUS product: N/A v: N/A serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: PRIME B560M-A v: Rev 1.xx
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 1601
    date: 05/07/2022
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i3-10100F bits: 64 type: MT MCP cache:
    L2: 1024 KiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 4195 min/max: 800/4300 cores: 1: 4172 2: 4209 3: 4200
    4: 4202 5: 4196 6: 4187 7: 4201 8: 4200
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650] driver: nouveau v: kernel
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: gpu: nouveau resolution: 1920x1080~144Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NV167 v: 4.3 Mesa 22.0.5
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-58-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-V driver: e1000e
  IF: eno1 state: down mac: c8:7f:54:5a:fd:ee
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    driver: rtl8192ee
  IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: 14:eb:b6:44:4d:27
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 108.25 GiB (22.7%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Patriot model: M.2 P300 512GB size: 476.94 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 467.89 GiB used: 108.24 GiB (23.1%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 5.2 MiB (1.0%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 4.5 MiB (0.2%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 27.8 C mobo: N/A gpu: nouveau temp: 26.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 281 Uptime: 26m Memory: 15.48 GiB used: 3.51 GiB (22.7%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13
```

Edit: I'm adding this text to the post so it's easier for others to find this post if they do a web search:

PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
device [8086:43bd] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[ 0] RxErr
AER: Corrected error received: 000:00:1c.5

Comment: "*I just finished building a new PC.*" -- Congratulations. Did you follow basic safety rules for static discharge? Did you avoid putting  skin oils (e.g. fingerprints) on electrical contacts/pins? Did you run any diagnostics and/or a memory test?

Comment: @sawdust Yes I followed safety rules, yes I avoided touching pins and contacts. Yes I've run some basic tests. Do you have any diagnostic tools in mind specifically?